# Pan audio tracks in an AVMutableVideoComposition

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-audio, audiounit, avmutablecomposition

I've created an app that allows mixing of several videos and their respective audio tracks.  I can edit the volume levels just fine using an AVAudioMix, but what I would really like to be able to do is to adjust the pan of each audio track.  I know pan can be adjusted for AudioUnits, but I cant see how audiounits could be used with an AVMutableVideoComposition.  Panning is also available on AVAudioPlayers, but again this is a different area of AVFoundation.  Does anyone know how I could pan the different audio tracks of a video composition like this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this might be possible using MTAudioProcessorTap.  Theres a project provided by apple here : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AudioTapProcessor/Introduction/Intro.html .  This demonstrates how you can take an AVAssetTrack and apply a band pass filter - but potentially you can apply any AudioUnit effect - pan being a basic one.  There are stereo vue meters in this project too.  Its taken me many days to find this solution, seems its something that is little used.